# Multi Segments in a progress bar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, progress-bar

I am looking for Multi Segments in a progress bar jQuery plugin.

Each segments can have different width and different background colour.

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

I have tired googling around, I can't find any jquery progress bar plugin that support Multi segments support.

Does that plugin exist?

Answer (score 0):

with jquery-ui you can create segments inside the .ui-progressbar-value

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: 0,
  create: function( event, ui ) {
      var progress=$(this);
      var progressvalue=progress.children(".ui-progressbar-value");
      progressvalue.css("overflow","hidden");
      var wrapper=$("<div>");
      wrapper.css({"width":progress.width(),"height":"100%","display":"block"});
      progressvalue.append(wrapper);         
      var segment=$("<span>");
      segment.css({"width":"20%","height":"100%","display":"block","background":"#aa0000","float":"left"});
      wrapper.append(segment);
      segment=$("<span>");
     segment.css({"width":"50%","height":"100%","display":"block","background":"#00aa00","float":"left"});
      wrapper.append(segment);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9fDy3/